# NHibernate generator for a property value (either from a sequence or autoincrement)

Tags: nhibernate, oracle10g

I have the following nHibernate Mapping and a corresponding class. The mapping works fine. 
I want the value of the field 'RfpId' to be auto inserted starting from '1'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="IBeam.Core.Models" assembly="IBeam.Core" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="Rfp" table="EST_MRFP" schema="test$tran">
    <id name="Id" type="long">
        <generator class="sequence" >
            <param name="sequence">test$masters.global_sequence</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="RfpId" column="RfpId" type="String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Title" column="Title" type="String" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I do this? Right now I have created an oracle sequence 'RfpSequence'. And before every new record of type `Rfp` is inserted, I fetch the NEXTVAL from `RfpSequence` by running a query. Is there any way where nHibernate can do this for me, just like it does for the `Id` field.

Comment: FrpId is a defined as a string, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Is the database responsible for the increment? If so try:-

```
<property name="RfpId" generated="always" update="false" insert="false" />
```

There is caveat as NH will need to perform a select straight after the insert to update the value.